# OS monitoring using Java

Tags: java, c

I'm planning to implement a framework for monitoring OS level resources:

- process
- network stats
- cpu info etc

using Java.

I see there is SIGAR API by Spring, which is implemented in native language and Java API being provided on top.

But I will prefer not to have native stuff in my framework, rather for each OS will write a Java Class which will fetch required OS info by running system commands via Java Runtime.

So I would like to have inputs/suggestions that one may have seen of not doing this in Java
and use native app/api/jni. Any example will help for sure.
I agree each OS has different commands to get these stats, but will prefer to have a Java Class per OS than have/load native code.

Comment: Pure Java will not provide much in the way of low level OS monitoring.  You need to use the OS specific functions as these provide different information for different OSes. e.g. using JMX you can get the load average, provided you are running on Unix.

Comment: Why are you typing Java in capital letters...?

Comment: wait... so why did you tag this C?

Comment: @Mike So people know what he doesn't want. ;)

Comment: On POSIX (unix, linux) you should be able to use `procfs`. It's a virtual filesystem (you just need to read files) that represents the kernels state. (Except for file io actually being a native operation) you could stay on the java side.

Comment: :-) thanks @Mike corrected typo with Java...And yes Peter is right I tagged this C because like to also know C experts suggestions over monitoring. Java has came so far, do we still need to do such things via C API/Wrapper/JNI thing. Why not only Java?? thats my main point here for even doing OS level thing. OR point out what Java lacks in this area which SIGAR APIs are solving

Answer (score 0):

I have used  SIGAR API with great success. I would recommend using it, it sounds like it is exactly what you need.